# how to disjoin two sets?

Tags: clojure

I have two sets and need to create a third one, which will include elements from the first one that are absent in the second one:

```
(? #{"a" "b" "c"} #{"b"}) ; -> ["a" "c"]
```

I know about [`disj`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/disj), but it works only when the second argument is an element, not a set.

Comment: To remove any collection of stuff from a set, not just another set, you can combine disj with `reduce`, as in: `(reduce disj #{1 2 3} [3 4 5])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have two sets, you can use [set difference](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.set-api.html#clojure.set/difference):

```
user=> (require 'clojure.set)
user=> (difference #{"a" "b" "c"} #{"b"})
#{"a" "c"}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there wasn't a difference function, you might have created it easily with reduce:

```
=> (reduce disj #{"a" "b" "c" "d"} #{"b" "d"})
#{"a" "c"}
```

Reduce takes a function, an initial 'accumulator' and a collection it maps over to modify the accumulator. In this case it would use the first set as an accumulator, remove the first item from the second set from it, then the next, etc.

Comment: I think this is how difference is implemented for the general case. The nice thing about this is you can replace the second set with any collection (list, vector, seq, etc) and it will still work.

Comment: Sorry Alex, didn't notice you had posted the exact same solution in the comments to the OP.

Comment: No worries - I didn't bother writing it up as an answer so I consider it fair game :)